# How to call handler methods in an initializer? creating webhooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, event-handling

I want to receive stripe web-hooks live and in order to do that I have to use an initializer. Using Stripe_events gem.  Im not too familiar with initializers, but I'm here to learn!

-I want my `event`(webhook) to get called with the handler_method.

My initializers/stripe.rb

```rails
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]


StripeEvent.configure do |events|
    events.subscribe 'charge.succeeded', ReservationsController.new
    events.all = AllEvents.new



end
```

As you can see I set events.all = AllEvents.new
I want to call all of the events into this one stripe_handler. Based on what the event.type is Ex.`'charge.succeeded'`

```
if event.type == 'charge.succeeded' 

etc........

end
```

in app/stripe_handlers/all_events.rb

```rails
class AllEvents
  def call(event)

    if event.type == 'charge.succeeded'

        reservation = Reservation.find_by_transaction_id(event.object.id)
        reservation.update_attributes pay_completed: true

        # reservation = Reservation.find_by_transaction_id
    elsif event.type == 'customer.created'


    elsif event.type == 'account.application.deauthorized'

            # look out for account.updated and check if the account ID is unknown

  end
end
end
```

All in all, I want to send the events.all values to the handler_methods where I can make actions for each webhook.

Comment: hmm, when you say "all values to the handle_method", do you mean like individual methods to handle various events? If that's the case, then I don't understand what's stopping you from making the individual "handler_methods".

Comment: yes! like this `def call(event)` is suppose to receive the event and then inside i use the event value which is the specific event that was just sent as a webhook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to put this in comments but it's too big for a comment. After quickly reading the documentation [here](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event#usage), I have written down below of my understanding of how to use the `stripe_event` gem.

So, `initializers/stripe.rb` you need something like the code block below. All you need to do is call `events.subscribe` in the configure block with the name of the event and an instance of class which would handle that event. You don't need to handle all the events using just one object.

```
StripeEvent.configure do |events|
    events.subscribe 'charge.succeeded', ChargeSucceeded.new
    event.subscribe 'customer.created', CustomerCreated.new
    event.subscribe 'account.application.deauthorized', Deauthorised.new
end
```

Then the classes which handle the events would look something like this:

```
class ChargeSucceeded
  def call(event)
    #Code to handle event 'charge.succeeded'
  end
end

class CustomerCreated
  def call(event)
    #Code to handle event 'customer.created'
  end
end

class Deauthorised
  def call(event)
    #Code to handle event 'account.application.deauthorized'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yea that was my initial thought until a guy on there support side said its a good idea to just call all of the events into one, but yea ill just do it this way. also you're creating separate controllers for each one? is that alot of controllers? or can i have multiple classes in a controller?

Comment: @MichaelLombardo Sorry, these aren't rails controllers. These are just plain ruby classes which have a method `call` and take `event` as an argument. I have edited my answer to not use the word controller as it's bit confusing. All the controller level handling is done in the gem and the gem only uses one controller see [here](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event/blob/master/app/controllers/stripe_event/webhook_controller.rb)

Comment: Im getting an error /Users/michael/Desktop/projects/ScribeOwl/config/initializers/stripe.rb:13:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ChargeSucceeded